# Why i'm having the methods of my subclass?

Tags: swift, class, object, types

```
class MediaItem {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Movie: MediaItem {
    var director: String
    init(name: String, director: String) {
        self.director = director
        super.init(name: name)
    }
}

class Song: MediaItem {
    var artist: String
    init(name: String, artist: String) {
        self.artist = artist
        super.init(name: name)
    }
}

var song : MediaItem = Song(name: "Mateo",artist: "Romeo")
```

I understand that song is a `MediaItem` instance but I'm initializing it with a `Song` instance.

What type is my song? Is it a `MediaItem` or a `Song`?

Which method should I be using?

```
var song : MediaItem = Song(name: "Mateo",artist: "Romeo")
```

or

```
var song = Song(name: "Mateo",artist: "Romeo")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`song` is a `Song` instance which you declared to be `MediaItem` instance.  A song may be a media item (by inheritance), but a media item is not necessarily a song.

```
var song : MediaItem = Song(name: "Mateo",artist: "Romeo")

song.dynamicType // Song.Type
song is Song // true
song is MediaItem // true
song is Movie // false

song.name // "Mateo"
song.artist // Value of Type 'MediaItem' has no member 'artist'
```

*The 'gotcha' in declaring it as a `MediaItem` is that you can't explicitly downcast `song` without forcing the downcast, [as explained on the Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23)*

```
song as Song // raises the error "'MediaItem' is not convertible to 'Song'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?"
song as! Song // forced downcast is allowed
```

Type inference is the preferred approach; it is more readable and concise to use:

```
var song = Song(name: "Mateo",artist: "Romeo")
```

Comment: Hey i don't catch it :( var song : MediaItem = Song(name: "Mateo",artist: "Romeo") so song it's a mediaitem or a Song? Sorry but i'm trying to understand the english too :(

Comment: It's a `Song` that you told the compiler was a `MediaItem`.  Because you lied to the compiler about its type, it's treating it as a media item, even though it is, in actuality, a song instance.